# Can't spoil a young baby with attention?

Tags: psychology, children, parenting

*Your Baby's First Year* by [the American Academy of Pediatrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Academy_of_Pediatrics)<sup>[1]</sup>, in a chapter about very young babies, includes the following paragraph:

> The best way to handle crying is to respond promptly to your infant whenever he cries during his first few months. You cannot spoil a young baby by giving him attention; and if you answer his calls for help, he'll cry less overall.

I wonder what evidence there is for "You cannot spoil a young baby by giving him attention". Was there, perhaps, a longitudinal study done of children who were paid less and more attention, and how spoiled they were — which I take to mean how much attention they demanded — when they were older? Is the claim pure conjecture on the AAP's part? Or what?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> It's actually edited by one Steven P. Shelov, but has the imprimatur of the AAP. The edition I'm quoting from is the June 1998 Bantam edition, ISBN 0-553-57904-5, and the quotation is from page 52.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3498

Comment: If only we had a reliable source for this statement. Maybe we could check with the American Academy of Pediatrics to see if they know anything about it?

Comment: @DJClayworth, excellent idea. I'll e-mail the mailbox `info` at the server `healthychildren.org` (an official AAP address), pointing to this page, and see if they reply here or via e-mail. If the latter, I'll update here.

Comment: Okay, done. And I included Dr. Shelov on the e-mail as a recipient as well.

Comment: The Shelov address was wrong, and delivery failed. Awaiting a reply from the AAP, though.

Comment: Without a clear definition of 'spoil' it's always gonna be a challenge to answer this.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you cannot spoil someone who is not able to anticipate that if he cries the care-giver will come to help. I've read from different sources that this developmental milestone is achieved when babies are 9-12 months, eg. here: http://www.cde.ca.gov/sp/cd/re/itf09cogdevfdcae.asp

The reference given is Lerner & Ciervo 2003. My guess is that it refers to:
Lerner & Ciervo 2003. Healthy Minds: Nurturing Children’s Development from 0 to 36 Months.
http://www.zerotothree.org/child-development/brain-development/9-12months.pdf

This document is in turn apparently based on a report by the NAS:
National Research Council. From Neurons to Neighborhoods: The Science of Early Childhood Development. Washington, DC: The National Academies Press, 2000.
http://www.nap.edu/catalog.php?record_id=9824
But I haven't found the relevant part by flicking through this over-600-pages report.